# How can I prevent user entered password from showing on screen?

Tags: python, shell, interface

I am trying to create a utility program, but after the password is correctly typed in it goes to the main screen, and shows the password right above it! Is there any way I can automatically make the program clear the shell before it goes to the main menu?

Comment: The proper way to input a password is with `stty -echo`. Then clearing the screen will not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute the `"clear"`(linux/mac) or `"cls"`(windows) command based on your OS.

```
>>> import subprocess,sys
>>> if sys.platform in ("linux2", "linux", "darwin"): #for linux / mac
...     subprocess.call("clear")
... elif sys.platform.statswith("win"):    #for windows
...     subprocess.call("cls")
```

List of possible [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform) values:

```
System               platform value
Linux (2.x and 3.x)  'linux2'
Linux (py 3.3)       'linux'
Windows              'win32'
Windows/Cygwin       'cygwin'
Mac OS X             'darwin'
OS/2                 'os2'
OS/2 EMX             'os2emx'
RiscOS               'riscos'
AtheOS               'atheos'
```

Comment: Might I recommend using a `try: except:` block to attempt the linux/mac method, and then use the windows method on exception?  It should raise an `OSError` specifically.  This might make it more portable.

Comment: @SethMMorton `sys.platform` is a better option.

Comment: I think a 'reset' command is a better option.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary Sure.  Let me rephrase my comment.  Might I recommend using `sys.platform` to check the platform and use the proper method?  This might make it more portable.